Next JS Could not find module in the React Client Manifest
I have a custom Accordion component that accepts AccordionItem components. Both are client components!
On the AccordionItem.tsx file i export not only the component, but a namespace as well for the header and body parts... like this:
"use client"

/// some code

export default AccordionItem ...

export namespace AccordionItem {
    export function Header({...
        
          // code
         
        export function Body({...
}

When i use this component NextJS throws the following Unhandled Runtime Error
Error: Could not find the module "//components/accordion/AccordionItem.tsx#AccordionItem#Header" in the React Client Manifest. This is probably a bug in the React Server Components bundler.
The component works well on any regular React project, but not on Next JS 14.2.12
After searching for a while, came across a github issue where someone suggested to simply use "use client" on the component where the Accordion/AccordionItem is being used, and even tho it "fixes" the problem...it makes my component to be rendered on the client side, which I don't want.
Does anyone know a better workaround for this? Or do we just have to wait for next's team?
Note
The problem seems to be caused by typescript namespaces. When using an import like MyNamespace.something, next throws an error saying that it can't find the module MyNamespace#something.
But even if I separate my namespace into multiple files, the same can't be done for 3rd party packages like framer motion.
Relevant Info

NextJS 14.2.12
Framer Motion 11.5.5
Typescript 5


To resolve this issue without rendering the entire component on the client side, try separating the interactive parts (like Header and Body) into distinct client components. Use “use client” only in these components. This way, the rest of the component can remain server-side.

Hey thanks for the help! Unfortunately it doesn't solve the problem because framer motion also uses namespaces... like motion.div. End's up throwing the same error but now for framer motion's module.

Alright, I understand. It seems that the namespace conflict is causing issues with both modules. One approach you could try is aliasing the imports to avoid the conflict.
For example:
import { motion as framerMotion } from 'framer-motion';
import { motion as anotherMotion } from 'another-library';
This way, you can differentiate between the two motion objects and avoid the namespace conflict. Let me know if this helps or if you need further assistance!

I tried that, even tried import * as framerMotion from "framer-motion", but the same error still persists.
I don't have 2 motion libraries tho, only framer motion, and the problem is not to avoid conflicts... it's just that i'm not being able to use namespaces in nextjs :/
